# Typo3 RealUrl: add term to pagination url

Tags: typo3, realurl

I wrote a press release plugin listing several releases using the paginate widget. Using RealUrl the URL of the listing site looks like this: www.mysite.com/press/2/

Is it possible to add another term to the page parameter? So it looks like this: www.mysite.com/press/page-2/

I would also need this for two languages.

This is part of my RealUrl configuration:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
  'fixedPostVars' => array(
    '127' => array(  // Press release overview
      array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_press_releaselist[@widget_0][currentPage]',
      )
    ),
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use a `valueMap`. Only downside would be that you would provide every value. So if you expect 100 pages, you need to add those 100 numbers to the realurl configuration.